# On button click wait

Tags: unity, android, scene, coroutines

I have a button I got from google material design asset pack which has a ripple animation when pressed. I'm using the button's click option in the inspector that calls a method that switches scenes. But when I tap the button it switches the scene immediately and feels unnatural since the animation hasn't finished the button ripples animation.

I tried using co-routines. Made the button call a method in which I call a IEnumerator method (since the button can't directly call a co-routine) and then switch the scene. But that doesn't work since it starts the co-routine and switches the scene, the co-routine never pauses the code and never finishes (probably because I loaded a new scene and the object that carries the script isn't transferred).

Code example:

The method that gets called when I tap a button:

```
 public void OnButtonTap()
 {
     StartCoroutine(Wait(0.2f));
     SceneManager.LoadScene("OnePlayerGameIntro");
 }
```

The wait coroutine:

```
 public IEnumerator Wait(float seconds)
 {
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(seconds);
 }
```

Comment: There's [another good answer to a similar question here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/150994/39518), showing how to make a generic "Wait, then to this Action" coroutine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the method with the coroutines.

```
 public void OnButtonTap()
 {
     StartCoroutine(LoadSceneAfterDelay("OnePlayerGameIntro", 0.2f));
 }


 public IEnumerator LoadSceneAfterDelay(string sceneName, float seconds)
 {
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(seconds);
     SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneName);
 }
```

Coroutines can't pause the "main thread" of Unity. A coroutine is a parallel execution of a piece of code and runs "independently" of the main thread.

Comment: I used invoke and it worked, I'm probably going to use this since I can use the method and don't have to create 2 methods for every scene change.

Comment: Yes you have, one to call Invoke, the other to call the SceneManager. Anyway, it's up to you ;)

Comment: But when I want to load a scene in an another place I need to write it just once and call the method to load. Could write a singleton to access the method from the main script.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Invoke` method. `Invoke` is used to trigger *another* method, but it allows us to pass a `float` value, representing a "wait" before the method runs.

Note that `Invoke` takes a `string` for the method name. Simple type out the *name* of the method with *no enclosing brackets* inside *double quotation marks*, as shown, in the example. Also note that you can not call methods that take parameters, in this way.

---

```
///<summary>Opens the scene immediately.</summary>
public void OpenScene
{
    // put your logic to open the scene here
}

///<summary>Opens the scene after a 0.3 second delay.</summary>
public void OpenSceneWithWait()
{
    Invoke("OpenScene", 0.3f);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Unity animations you could take advantage of Animation Events. This will allow you to trigger code at a specific point in an animation. This should allow you to be more accurate than using a co-routine or invoke method.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-AnimationEvents.html